# Twitch Chat box in selenium

Tags: python-2.7, browser, scripting, automation, twitch

Well I pieced together a script with multiple google searches which is based on selenium,**the intention of this code is to try to type in the chat box of twitch with a randomized message automatically(not limited use to only my channel)**, but it fails miserably. I have a general knowledge on python but that's it, which is why ended up here since I couldn't find the answer myself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from random import randint
import keyboard
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.twitch.tv/alexaki99')
#getting chat box
chat=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > div.tw-full-height.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-relative > div > div.right-column.tw-full-height.tw-flex-shrink-0.tw-relative > div > div > div.tw-full-width.tw-full-height.tw-z-default.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-grow-1.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-relative > div.tw-full-width.tw-full-height.tw-overflow-hidden.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-grow-1.tw-flex-shrink-1 > div > div.chat-input.tw-pd-b-2.tw-pd-x-2 > div.tw-z-default.tw-relative > div:nth-child(1) > textarea')
time.sleep(40) #manually logging in because of captcha
print 'done sleep' #verification that the delay
chat.click()
while True:
    num=(randint(0, 7))
    if num==1:
        chat.send_keys('1')
    if num==2:
        chat.send_keys('2')
    if num==3:
        chat._send_keys('3')
    if num==4:
        chat._send_keys('4')
    if num==5:
        chat._send_keys('5')
    if num==6:
        chat._send_keys('6')
    if num==7:
        chat._send_keys('7')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('shift+q'):
        break
driver.quit()
```

The error I get goes as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\twitch_auto.py", line 11, in <module>
    chat.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

I'm aware I could use irc twitch but I got lost quick,so I stayed with what I had.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected result of your script and what is the actual result—browser behavior and console output?

Comment: Like mentioned < the intention of this code is to try to type in the chat box of twitch with a randomized message automatically(not limited use to only my channel > but I forgot to add that I get this error : https://i.imgur.com/DBaynoP.png and it just stops there,haven't tried the shift+q action,nothing changes from browser end as well

Comment: Please update your original question to include the *text* of the error output (not an *image*).

Comment: Well answering to my own question:
I fcked up the timer and had it before I logged in, meaning it would try to find the chat log while I was trying to log in and after that I changed "send_keys" to all numbers (like I should have) and imported "from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys" that way I could add a line for me to press enter and voila,it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The "chat" you had specified is the box that you type your `message("done sleep")`.

You have to do the same process you did finding the chat element, but now with the button element that you have on bottom right. After you found your buttom element, just need to do `buttom.click()`.

Comment: Sorry I haven't touched this in a long time but the problem was solved as you can see bellow the question.
From what I get you're saying that I'm attempting to type "done sleep" but that's not the case, this message was for me to see in python what I was typing was "1" "2" "3" and so on.  
As for the button,as far as I remember, It able able to click it on separate testing, the problem wasn't that but the timer as mentioned in the comments, I changed that with hotkey as 2 give a command  when 2 start  (enter on numpad) and it worked or I put button.click() in while by accident, who knows.